# How to configure an existing git repo to be shared by a UNIX group

Tags: git, permissions, share, shared

I have an existing git repo (a bare one) which has up to this point only been writable by me.  I want to open it up to some UNIX user group, foo, so that all members of foo can push to it.  I'm aware that I can easily set up a *new* git repo with:

```
git init --bare --shared=group repodir
chgrp -R foo repodir
```

But I need the equivalent operation for an *existing* repo dir.

Comment: There’s **[an excellent answer to this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine)** over on ServerFault (another StackOverflow site).

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Try this to make an existing repository in `repodir` work for users in group `foo`:

```
chgrp -R foo repodir                 # set the group
chmod -R g+rw repodir                # allow the group to read/write
chmod g+s `find repodir -type d`     # new files get group id of directory
git init --bare --shared=all repodir # sets some important variables in repodir/config ("core.sharedRepository=2" and "receive.denyNonFastforwards=true")
```

Comment: I would add that you probably should also set config.sharedRepository = true in the repo's config.  http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was doing on my own, but I wanted to get some external confirmation.  Thanks.  :)  I was also hoping there would be a git clone --shared=group sort of thing, but clone's --shared option does something completely different.

Comment: You can use the `git init --shared` command on an existing repo to set the config value. You also need to do the `chmod` command to get the permissions of the files right.

Comment: To confirm this also helps if you're in a mess because someone has done a `git pull` etc. as root rather than as `www-data` or whatever the owner is and as a result you get `error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects`.  I thought I'd fixed the ownership of all files/directories that were wrong by using `find` and `-type d`/`type -f`, but only this method got rid of the error (prob. because a file in some subdirectory weren't group writeable?)

Comment: @LaurentG - It was a good edit. And the author also [accepted it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group/3242364#comment3349064_3242364). Any reason behind the roll back? Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216212/187824) for more.

Comment: When I set `core.sharedRepository` the new object folders did get group write permission as expected - however not the contained object files themselves. Is that correct ? Wondering since the above repair commands _do_ set the group write permission also on the object files.

Comment: The user's umask still seems to apply to newly-created files. Is that what you expect? I would think the documentation of `core.sharedRepository` would mention this - it seems useless without users making all of their files group writeable.

Comment: how did you created that foo group ?

Answer (score 54):

Merging [@David Underhill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3242364/3763649) and [@kixorz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9537992/3763649) answers, I made my own (definitive) solution.

It is for **bare** repos and **non-bare** repos. There are only little differences between them, but in this way is clearer.

**BARE REPOSITORY**

```
cd <repo.git>/                            # Enter inside the git repo
git config core.sharedRepository group    # Update the git's config
chgrp -R <group-name> .                   # Change files and directories' group
chmod -R g+w .                            # Change permissions
chmod g-w objects/pack/*                  # Git pack files should be immutable
find -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +         # New files get directory's group id
```

where:

- `<repo.git>` is the bare repository directory, typically on the server (e.g. `my_project.git/`).
- `<group-name>` is the group name for git users (e.g. *users*).

---

**NON-BARE REPOSITORY**

```
cd <project_dir>/                         # Enter inside the project directory
git config core.sharedRepository group    # Update the git's config
chgrp -R <group-name> .                   # Change files and directories' group
chmod -R g+w .                            # Change permissions
chmod g-w .git/objects/pack/*             # Git pack files should be immutable
find -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +         # New files get directory's group id
```

where:

- `<project_dir>` is the project directory containing the `.git` folder.
- `<group-name>` is the group name for git users (e.g. *users*).

Comment: As Charles said, also do: `chmod g-w objects/pack/*` (if non-bare repository, prepend `.git/`)

Comment: here how can we find the group name or how to create the group name?

Comment: 'chmod g+s `find . -type d`' raises error `unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long`

Comment: As @Dr.X noted, `chmod g+s \`find . -type d\`` does not scale. Use `find -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +`

Comment: I think all the loose objects should also be read-only based on the pre-shared state.  Maybe something like `chmod g-w objects/*/*`.  I'm not sure about the info subdirectory though since it's empty for this repo.

Comment: You can save the hassle of `chmod g+w -R` and `chmod g+w .git/objects/pack/*` by running `chmod g=u` which applies the user's permissions to the group's permission–may they be writable or not. This is more suitable if the repo contains read-only files or Git will create other read-only files some day.

Comment: @Andrea, for the non-bare repo, shouldn't we `cd .git` before altering permissions?  The point is to make the repo shareable, not to alter the working tree file attributes...

Answer (score 50):

In the repo dir execute following commands:

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
chgrp -R foo repodir
chmod -R g+w repodir
```

Edit: To address frequent confusion, `group` is an actual keyword, you're not supposed to replace this with the name of the group.

Comment: Where `group` is NOT the name of the group :)

Comment: Object and pack files should be immutable; they should have permissions 444 / r--r--r--.

Comment: After trying `git config core.sharedRepository dev` then typing `git config` I get `fatal: bad config value for 'core.sharedrepository' in .git/config` in `git version` `1.7.0.4` (and possibly versions after)

Comment: `git config core.sharedRepository group` `group` is not the name of the group, but the actual value!

Comment: If you've made the mistake of using your group name instead of "group", just open .git/config in text editor and edit the core.sharedRepository line to say "group".

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not necessary, but it's worth pointing out that `git init --bare --shared` also sets the **denyNonFastForwards** option.

```
git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true
```

The meaning of this option is as follows:

> `receive.denyNonFastForwards`
>
> If you rebase commits that you’ve already pushed and then try to push
>   again, or otherwise try to push a commit to a remote branch that
>   doesn’t contain the commit that the remote branch currently points to,
>   you’ll be denied. This is generally good policy; but in the case of
>   the rebase, you may determine that you know what you’re doing and can
>   force-update the remote branch with a -f flag to your push command.

(from http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers of allowing a group to read/write you also need to add the user to the group (say "foo").

```
sudo usermod -a -G [groupname] [username]
```

Note: you will have to first create user if it doesn't exist