# git pull from CGI-Script ran by 'nobody'

Tags: git, perl, apache, ssh, cgi

I've got a git repository on a webserver (Apache), which is set up inside the home-directory of user `a`.

```
git clone ssh://a@git_url:7999/path/to/repository/repo.git
```

The git-repository is hosted on a stash-server. The authentication works via an ssh-key for the user a.

Now I'm trying to build a CGI-script which shows me some excerpts from `git log` on that repository. That works pretty much, but I just can't seem to be able to `git pull` inside the CGI-script since it's not run by user `a`, but by user `nobody`. The user `nobody` has no permissions to read the contents of the git-repository cloned by `a` and doesn't have an ssh-key set up on the stash-server.

Is there a way to run `git pull` from within the CGI-script in a way that it "masks" as user `a` so that it's able to pull?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html

Comment: I'm afraid that this solution is not for me, since I'm not the administrator of the server in questions, thus I can't just install stuff on that, and it's questionable that the administrators will install and configure this just for me.

Comment: Aren't there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have at least three options.

1. Create a separate clone that `nobody` owns.
2. Modify the clone that `a` owns to be [assigned to a group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3242364/123109) to which both `a` and `nobody` belong.
3. Create a cron job that runs as `a` to periodically run `git fetch` on the repository. Make the repository world-readable. You may need to modify your CGI program to operate in terms of `origin/master` rather than `master`, for example.

For options 1 and 2, you will need to arrange for `nobody` to have access to Stash. One possibility there is to create a passwordless (unencrypted) SSH key for `nobody` and add the public key to Stash for authorization. This does entail some risk: anyone who obtains a copy of `nobody`’s secret key can easily do whatever `nobody` can.