# Git repo on server

Tags: git, ssh, webserver, repository

I want to achieve a private repo where multiple users can work on online as well as offline. 
I have managed to install a repository on my webserver using ssh with putty. 
Now i tried to clone the repo locally to the local working environment.

I used gitbash in the directory I wanted to work in (under windows 7).

I used the following command:

```
$git clone user@myhost:folder/folderOfRepo
```

I got asked for my password. After I entered it I got this message:

> "fatal:folder/folderOfRepo does not appear to be a git repository
>
> "fatal:could not read from remote repository
>
> Please make sure you have
>   the correct access rights and the repository exists."

First question: is my overall approach correct for achieving what I want?
If the answer is yes,  then my second question is: what am I doing wrong that the repository won't clone?

I solved the problem using a / before the root folder, I used git clone user@myhost:/folder/folderOfRepo and it cloned my repo

Now I made some changes to the files inside the repo I've cloned, and used

> git push

and get the following error:

> remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
>   By default updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent.

I don't understand what is going wrong and why?

Comment: what is the result of git remote

Comment: What do you mean by git remote?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up your authentication with git. Checkout [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use#cloning-with-https-recommended) for setting up to clone with https. Then,`git clone https://yoururl.com/user/reponame.git`

Comment: What does Github have to do with the OP's question? He's hosting the git himself.

Comment: I've enabled ssl so I can use a https link. However I did notice I can't access any folders, only files. Does this have anything to do with permissions and how do I change them?

Comment: You need to have a group with users (yourself included) with proper permissions. Have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group

Comment: For multiple users, do I need to make multiple users in git, or is it possible to use the same user on multiple devices?