# Share a git-annex repository with a Unix group

Tags: git, git-annex

I would like to make a repository readable and writable over ssh for all users of a given group.

A [quick search on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group/29646155#29646155) led me to the following procedure :

```sh
cd <project_dir>/                         # Enter inside the project directory
git config core.sharedRepository group    # Update the git's config
chgrp -R <group-name> .                   # Change files and directories' group
chmod -R g+w .                            # Change permissions
chmod g-w .git/objects/pack/*             # Git pack files should be immutable
find -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +         # New files get directory's group id
```

My question is simple : is it safe to apply it to a git-annex repository as well ? Also, is it enough ?