# git share repo with unix group : permission issues / COMMIT_EDITMSG created with wrong mode

Tags: git

I've been looking at [How to configure an existing git repo to be shared by a UNIX group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group) but unable to find out what's the problem :

```
$ git init --shared=group
$ touch test && git add test
$ git commit -m 'test'
```

Now, if another user commit he gets the message: `fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied` because the file mode is `-rw-r-----` (however the group is OK).

So of the files in `.git/objects/` don't have write permission for the group either

For the rest of it, all directory seems to have been created with the proper shared group and mode.

Do I miss something here ?

Comment: Have you looked at the commands in the **answer** of the question you linked?

Comment: could be an issue with the `umask` : it looks like whoever created that file had a umask set to "don't give group write access" when he/she created that file. The owner of the file is probably the user that ran the `git commit` command that created that file. You would have to select a way to unify the environment settings of everyone interacting with that repo.

Comment: There is a comment in the question you linked, which points to [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/27040/191742), which does indicate possible issues with umask, and also gives a possible solution using POSIX extended attributes.

Comment: Your issue, being with `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, seems to indicate the shared repository isn't a bare repo, which would only serve as a common push/pull target. If you are sharing an active repo, beware of all traps that could be triggered when several actions are run (like : `git status` is obsolete as soon as it displays its content, `git commit` may commit files added by another user, etc ...). Unless you have a really good and understood reason why you want to do that, I would strongly suggest to at least take the time to set up a common remote, not a shared working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably hit an issue with how the `umask` was set when another user created that file. In the question you linked, there is, in the comments, a link to [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/27040/191742), which describes in more details possible umask issues, and suggests to use POSIX extended attributes on the repo directory.

---

That being said : since your issue is with the `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` file, which is created/edited only when a user types `git commit`, this suggests you are sharing an *active working directory*, rather than a bare repo.

There are so many things that can go wrong if you start using concurrently the very same repository :

- you can't rely on `git status`, because perhaps Becca typed `git add foo` right afterwards,
- you can't rely on `git commit`, because perhaps Fred ran `git checkout side/branch` or Melysa ran `git reset HEAD~4` while you were typing your commit message,
- etc ...

Unless you really know what you are doing, do take the time to at least set a shared *bare repository*, which would be used as the target push/pull repo for all your team.