# Configured a group shared git repository on NFS but fail to push after one group member pushed his commit

Tags: git, permissions

Basically I followed the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29646155/3818556) to convert my existing git repository to one shared (writable) with a particular group. But one thing I forget to do is:

```
git config core.sharedRepository group
```

The "sharedRepositoy" config was originally not existed in "core".  After another group member X commit his changes, I can no longer push my changes.  More worse, in the .git/objects/ directory I saw the owner of some directories changed to user X instead of me; the group ID remain unchanged but the group permission becomes "r-s" instead of the expected original "rws".  Therefore I can no longer do "chmod" or "chown" to those directories.

Question #1: Why is this happening? I mean, what exactly are the user settings to make the group permission of those directories change from "rws" to "r-s"? Or is it simply because I didn't enable "sharedRepository" in the config?

Question #2: Is it possible to fix it myself without asking user X or system admin to fix it? I don't belong to sudoers but I am still a member of that group, with the "setgid" flag set, is there a way to use this to regain my control back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This question, and my answer here, probably belongs on Superuser or Unix&Linux.)

> Why is this happening? I mean, what exactly are the user settings to make the group permission of those directories change from "rws" to "r-s"? Or is it simply because I didn't enable "sharedRepository" in the config?

It's the lack of the shared-repository setting, yes:

- Git creates new directories to hold files, now and then.
- Git creates new files, now and then.
- Whenever Git makes these, it uses `mkdir` or `open`, and sets the Unix-level `mode` to `0777` (directory) or `0666` (file), but the OS then *clears* certain bits according to the current process's `umask`, which is normally `022`.
- Setting the shared-repository setting tells Git to call `umask(002)` early on, so that only *one* bit is cleared, instead of two.  The result is that directories are created as `rwxrwxr-x` and files are created as `rw-rw-r--`.  (The `s` you see (`rws` or `r-s`) is a separate bit, the *setgid* bit, that the OS provides on its own based on the containing directory.  The setgid bit causes the new file or directory's group ownership to be that of the containing directory; by propagating this bit into newly-created directories, newly-created files *within* those directories retain this feature.)

> Is it possible to fix it myself without asking user X or system admin to fix it?

Possibly.  It's probably wiser to have an admin do it.

> I don't belong to sudoers but I am still a member of that group, with the "setgid" flag set, is there a way to use this to regain my control back?

Because you're in the correct group, you can, yourself, create your own directories.  You can set your own umask to `002` and make a directory:

```
umask 002; mkdir tmp
```

and then you can *copy* files within some incorrectly-permitted directory into the new one, then swap the names around:

```
cp 02/* tmp && mv 02 02-bad && mv tmp 02
```

for instance.  However, doing this *atomically* is not possible: these steps take time and someone else can run a Git command while that's going on.  If that happens, the copies may be inconsistent.  It's far simpler and less error-prone for some administrator to `chmod g+w` any directories and files for which this is required.  (If your `chmod` has it, `chmod -R g=u gitdir` is probably correct sufficient, though I have not tested it.)