# Not able to push files to remote git repository on local Git server

Tags: git, ubuntu

When I try to push my files to remote repository on a local git server it shows below error. Please help. The remote repository has chmod 777 access. So I dont think it is access related issue.

```
***nips@nips-OptiPlex-5090:~/myproject$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 1.35 KiB | 1.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
To 10.114.58.68:/srv/git/project.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@10.114.58.68:/srv/git/project.git'***
```

Comment: try ```git checkout master``` and then push like this```git push <GIT_REPO_SSH> master```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can log on to 10.114.58.68 as `git` (since it is an SSH URL), check the rights associated with the bare repository in `/srv/git/project.git`

Make sure, for instance, it is [accessible by the group of your user account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29646155/6309):

```
cd /srv/git/project.git                   # Enter inside the git repo
git config core.sharedRepository group    # Update the git's config
chgrp -R <group-name> .                   # Change files and directories' group
chmod -R g+w .                            # Change permissions
chmod g-w objects/pack/*                  # Git pack files should be immutable
find -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +         # New files get directory's group id
```

Note: Nothing should be owned by `root`, beside system files.
Do a `chown -R git:git /srv/git/project.git`.
Root has no business owning Git data.

Comment: The folder already has full access 777
`drwxrwxrwx 7 root root 4096 Jul 28 16:07 project.git`

Comment: @arunkannan Nothing should be owned by root, beside system file. Do a `chown -R git:git /srv/git/project.git`. Root has no business owning Git data.

Comment: @arunkannan Well done! Remember, using `root` should be only for admin tasks. For the rest, use a regular user account (or service account like `git` here)

Comment: @arunkannan So, that seems to be working, right?

Comment: Yessss!!      `git push origin master`
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 332 bytes | 332.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To :/srv/git/project.git

Comment: @arunkannan OK, that still looks like the push is completed successfully, right?

Comment: yep.......`git clone git@10.114.58.68:/srv/git/project.git`
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 8, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.

Comment: @arunkannan Great, clone works, push works. You are good to go.